# How to properly use properties of a class as arguments of its methods

Tags: php, oop

I want to use a private method in a class called by public methods from the same class.

```
class Foo 
{
    private $updateAll = true;
    private $updateA = false;
    private $updateB = false;

    public function updateA() 
    {   
        $this->updateAll = false;
        $this->updateA = true;
        $this->updateB = false;
        $this->update();
    }

    public function updateB()
    {   
        $this->updateAll = false;
        $this->updateA = false;
        $this->updateB = true;
        $this->update();
    }

    private function update()
    {   
        // Code here...

        if ($this->updateAll) {
            // set all api call params
        }

        if ($this->updateA) {
            // set api call param 
        }

        if ($this->updateB) {
            // set api call param
        }

        // Code here...
    }
}
```

Is this a proper use of class properties as arguments?
It works but I don't know whether there is a better way to do this. My purpose is to kinda use dynamic method arguments without the need to pass 3 arguments to `update()`.

Comment: The code you see is too abstract to say anything useful about. Those properties (fields) should be parameters instead, and the method `_method()` looks like it should be three different methods or in a different class altogether.

Comment: seems legit to me i would just make function doA() and  function doB() and call both if($this->_property_all===true). You could also use just one field and set it as $this->do='A' or use a number.

Comment: @CodeCaster there is a lot of code inside _method() with just minor variations based on properties value.
Having 3 different methods is exactly what I want to avoid because every change should be done in all three places.
As for parameters you have a point but my question was how to bypass use of parameters.

Comment: _"every change should be done in all three places"_ - sounds like an excellent candidate for some refactoring, but again, no code: too abstract. _"my question was how to bypass use of parameters"_ - you shouldn't want to.

Comment: I've changed my code to make more sense why I don't want to use three methods.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not wrong and should work just fine as you say, but it does feel a bit weird... I think any of the following approaches is cleaner and more flexible than your code. I'm sure there will be lots of other options perfectly valid, these are just some ideas...

- Multiple method arguments

As it's been suggested to you in the comments, I think the normal way to do that is actually just adding the arguments to the `update()` method...

```
class Updater
{
    public function update($all = true, $a = false, $b = false)
    {
        // Code...
    }
}
```

- One constant method argument

*However*, in your example, the options seem to be mutually exclusive (any combination of 2 options is redundant), so you can do perfectly fine with just one parameter!

```
class Updater
{
    const UPDATE_ALL = 'all';
    const UPDATE_A = 'a';
    const UPDATE_B = 'b';

    public function update($updateMode = self::UPDATE_ALL)
    {
        // Code...
    }
}
```

- Command pattern

If your example is not realistic, and you have a scenario with lots of options that are not mutually exclusive, I'd use something similar to a command pattern, where the class in charge to define the options of the operations is different from the class that performs the operation...

```
class Updater
{
    public function update(UpdateCommand $command)
    {
        // Code...
    }
}

class UpdateCommand
{
    public $paramA = false;
    public $paramB = false;
    // ...
    public $paramZ = false;
}
```

- Fluent interface

Or you could also use a fluent interface. Although that's a bit harder to test...

```
class Updater
{
    private $paramA = false;
    private $paramB = false;
    // ...
    private $paramZ = false;

    public function withA()
    {
        $this->paramA = true;
        return $this;
    }

    public function withB()
    {
        $this->paramB = true;
        return $this;
    }

    // ...

    public function withZ()
    {
        $this->paramZ = true;
        return $this;
    }

    public function run()
    {
        // Code...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input.
I think I will go with Command pattern because although my code doesn't reflect that, options are not exclusive. updateA will only send a certain param to API that's included in ALL obviously but not in updateB.

Comment: That's my favourite approach as well, if you want to go deeper in the use of commands, I suggest you to take a look at Tactician library http://tactician.thephpleague.com/